# DBCC CHECKDB running longer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ola-hallengren, dbcc-checkdb

We are using Ola's Maintenance solution and part of that we have job DatabaseIntegrityCheck - User Database and System Databases, sometimes job for some of the databases it's running longer like in days and sometimes also it's skipping the DB
We have Sql server 2012 (Sql Server version is 11.0.5388.0 -Standard) and database is not that much big like under 10GB.
Someone's help really appreciated!

### **Added:**

MAster DB is only 5 MB
Ola command:

```
sqlcmd -E -S $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR)) -d AdminDB -Q "EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseIntegrityCheck] @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', @LogToTable = 'Y'" -b
 DBCC CHECKDB ([master]) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS, DATA_PURITY
```

Script is not blocked, it's running for longer for Master and another user DB
Other Databases ran fine.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response.

Comment: We are using following command: DBCC CHECKDB ([master]) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS, DATA_PURITY

Comment: CommangLog table shows  StartTime 05/02/20,  EndTime = NULL, ErrorNumber = NULL, ErrorMessage = NULL

Comment: Thank you! I just edited into original question

Comment: Please add output of `select @@version` in the question

Comment: Sql Server version is 11.0.5388.0 -Standard

Answer (score 1):

There's a strong possibility that CU 4 for SP2 which was release in January of 2015 will resolve the issue you are experiencing: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3029825/fix-dbcc-checkdb-checktable-command-may-take-longer-in-sql-server-2012

That being said, you are running a SQL server that is out of support and SP2 CU 4 which should resolve the issue is out of support as well. You should go ahead and patch the server to the current SP4 CU 10 + the latest security updates.

It appears to me that you may also be running an old version of OLAs scripts based on the way you are calling them. They should be updated as well.

Comment: Yes, I see that but we were not in a position to apply the Service pack but we will apply the patch soon.
Yes, We are using older version of Ola script and we are in the process to update it.
We have in out To Do List to update the server.

Thank You!